# Switching between enum values in Java

Tags: java, enums

forgive me if this is a stupid question, but I was wondering if enums in Java worked similarly to integers. What I mean is, say I had an enum declared as

```
public enum Colour {
    BLACK, WHITE
}
```

Would I be able to switch between them the way I could switch between ints? Like

```
Colour newColour = !newColour;
```

Since as far as I am aware, they are basically ints in C. Is it similar at all?

Comment: No you can't do that. You also couldn't do it with `int`s in Java.

Comment: If you're looking for the *bitwise not* operator, that's `~` (in both C and Java). The logical not (`!`) cannot be used with `int` operands in Java. But Java `enum` constants are neither `int`s nor `boolean`s; they're objects, so you can't do that.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1575146

Comment: What did the compiler say when you tried to compile `Colour newColour = !newColour;` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure thing, you can achieve the same behavior by defining a `toggle` method inside your enum:

```
enum Colour {
    BLACK, WHITE;

    Colour toggle() {
        if (this.equals(BLACK))
            return WHITE;
        else
            return BLACK;
    }
}
```

The the usage is: `Colour newColour = oldColour.toggle();`

Comment: Note you can also use `this == BLACK`, as it may be more readable & faster

Comment: Maybe `return values()[1 ^ ordinal()];` to stick to bitwise tricks.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu `values()` creates a new array every time, so any performance gain from bit tricks is outweighed by cost of copying the values to the new array.

Comment: @Andreas That's a valid point; however, it wasn't meant to be a performance improvement.

Comment: @Clashsoft it's a good habit to use `equals` over of `==`. Most of the time what you really want is `equals`, but in this specific case they indeed return a similar result. As for readability I'd argue that it's a matter of opinion. And as for performance, even if there is a difference - it's totally negligible.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this, to support as many colours as you like.  This way, you don't have branching logic inside the method that returns the complement.

```
public enum Colour {
    BLACK(null), WHITE(BLACK), RED(null), CYAN(RED);

    private Colour complement;

    private Colour(Colour complement) {
        this.complement = complement;
        if (complement != null) {
            complement.complement = this;
        }
    }

    public Colour getComplement() {
        return complement;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @alfasin's solution, but more in line with your question:

```
public enum Colour {
    BLACK, WHITE;

    public Colour toggle() {
        return values()[~ordinal() & 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `1 - ordinal()`?

Comment: Thanks! Really I was just looking for a way to toggle values, I didn't need it to be a bitwise trick, but I appreciate the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an even shorter version:

```
private enum Colour {

    WHITE, BLACK;

    public Colour toggleMode() {
        return this.equals(WHITE) ? BLACK: WHITE;
    }
}
```